# Xcode doesn't show the iphone simulators as the destination

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I put my ios deployment target as 7.1 and when i uploaded my game to itunes connect, it said i need 3.5 screenshots and I only have an iphone 5 so I have to use the simulator but when I tried to change the scheme it doesn't show up the simulator options. Why does this happen? Thanks

Comment: which version of xcode your are using?

Answer (score 1):

Delete `Derived Data` and restart Xcode.
1) Open Terminal
2) rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
3) Restart Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You have to add screenshot for 3.5" because ios7.1 is also for iphone4s which have 3.5" screen.

You can find simulator at,
**open simulator -> Hardware Menu -> Device -> Manage Device**

In Manage device you can add simulator by clicking on **'+'** button which is at bottom left corner of the screen.

If you don't find the simulator here then you have to download from
**xcode->preferences->downloads** options

Comment: I know that but do you know how to get the simulator?

Comment: Actually never mind I accidentally pressed on the wrong simulator but the problem is I can't get the App on the simulator screen

Comment: quit your simulator, clean your project and then run.

Comment: Right now it needs to run the game on my iPhone instead of the simulator

Comment: mean's you are getting blank screen on running of app

Comment: I do t mean I have a blank screen, my icon doesn't appear on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one little thing:

To choose your building/running destiny.

When your real iOS Device is selected it looks like:

[image]

1 - Click on your iOS Device Name to select which device you want to simulate (iPhone 4S - 3,5 inch)

[image]

2 - Build/Run your project and your app will appear on the simulator you choosed.

Comment: I know that, what I'm trying to say is that the simulators don't appear below the iOS device